# MemoryError opening 5GB file using Python

Tags: json, python-2.7

I am getting MemoryError even after reading my 5GB json file line by line in python.Here is the code, I am using to do the job. As I am new to python just would like to get the solution with code:

```
with open("D:/2.5GB.json",'r') as json_file:

    for line in json_file:
        ret= line.find('435355ebe9f768da84e60340266c18cexx') 
        if ret<>-1:                              
            print "Found"    
            exit()
```

Comment: Try printing a message on each line of the for loop - does anything at all appear, or does the MemoryError occur first?

Comment: Loop is running that I already check.

Comment: Do I even want to know why you have 5GB of JSON in the first place?

Comment: Assuming this is actually the entirety of the code you're running, the only idea I have is that somehow storage is being kept for each instantiation of ret - maybe if you were to change it to if line.find(...) != -1 (and you should be using !=, not <>), you wouldn't run into the same issue. Failing that, I'd try to run it under 64-bit python if you're not already.

Comment: Is this really all the code? You're not storing anything to an array or such?

Comment: @OliverW. You don't use python to iterate through 5GB JSON files for the sole purpose of finding a single string, then exiting without providing any sort of information at all?

Comment: I have 10 random records that I need to check..I will make a loop once I get it resolved.Whats the other alternative? I can't load the file into database.

Comment: @furkle: Can you elaborate how to do instantiation of ret?

Comment: Try removing the line "ret=line.find(...)", and changing the next line from "if ret <> -1" to if line.find(...) != -1:" Make sure you remove the quotes. I really doubt that would change anything, but it's the only thing I can point to in your code that might affect anything.

Comment: Not working..getting same error

Comment: That's because the error does not come from this piece of code. Which version of python are you using? Can you please post your full code? If not, can you (re)test your own excerpt on the file?

Answer (score -1):

Answer from http://ikigomu.com/?p=1

> with open("my_large_file.txt", "r") as f:
>     for line in f:
>      (code here)

The way you're currently doing it is exhausting the memory limit of Python by trying to load the whole thing at once. This works because it loads one line in at a time.

Comment: That is what he's doing, isn't it? Though his post is misformatted, his first line is "with open("D:/2.5GB.json", 'r') as json_file:"

Comment: For line in loads the entire file into memory. Hence the out of memory issue.

Comment: His code is exactly the same as the example in the site you've posted. He's not doing for line in f.read() or f.readlines().

Comment: I am still getting same error after changing code to readlines()

Comment: @Sourav Don't do that - his answer is incorrect because he misread your code.